# how to install gephi on ubuntu saucy

Tags: apt, ppa

I have tried to add the PPA repo into my machine , and the used apt-get update
the error I have got :

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I tried to search about this error via launchpad/google/gephi but 
couldnt find the solution.

Comment: For Trusty 14.04, try my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/531515/257249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://launchpad.net/~rockclimb/+archive/gephi-daily) link shows that the PPA 
contains `gephi` package for precise and oneric only.So folllow the below steps to install gephi on Ubuntu 13.10.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rockclimb/gephi-daily
```

After adding the above repository, run the below command

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/rockclimb-gephi-daily-saucy.list
```

Replace the word `saucy` to `precise` and then save it.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now install `gephi` by running,

```
sudo apt-get install gephi
```

Comment: hello , thank you for the reply , and i can see its for precise and oneric , but iam trying to install it on saucy

Answer (score 5):

The method below will make use of the precise package for your saucy version. Beware that this can be potentially buggy since it has not been developed for versions other than oneiric and precise.

First remove the ppa you have already added using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:rockclimb/gephi-daily
```

and then open you `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add the following line to end of it

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu precise main
```

and then do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

to update the package-list and add gephi to is and then

```
sudo apt-get install gephi
```

to install gephi.

Comment: thank you for the help , but i think (witch i did) if you add the PPA its automaticlly added in source.list, yet i did what you said still same problem.

Comment: @AhmedAl-attar: I hope you added `precise` instead of `saucy`.

Comment: hello , yes i did , but when i apt-get update its says saucy, ill try to remove the ppa and re-add the source.list

Comment: hello , ive removed the (ppa): sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:rockclimb/gephi-daily , and added the sources like Avinash Raj said , and its works fine now. thanks guys

Comment: Edit your answer and then include the code to remove the previously added repository.