# Problem installing Gephi after installing PPA and Oracle Java 8

Tags: software-installation

I have been having some issues with installing gephi recently on Trusty. The following are in my repository:

```
http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-testing/ubuntu trusty main
http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

When I

```
sudo apt-get install gephi
```

I get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gephi : Depends: libgoogle-collections-java but it is not installable
```

When I tried to look for the package, it says that the repo is no longer being updated. I then managed to find an old copy of the package here:

https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/libgoogle-collections-java

But for some reason when i tried to install it using:
tar -zxvf 'tarball'

Nothing seems to be happening. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Edit: The splash screen appears, and gehpi seems to try to initialize. However it seems to fail and stop after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to fix this is to go to:

```
sudo gedit /etc/environment
```

and add:

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java"
```

Then run the script normally

```
./bin/gephi
```

Answer (score 0):

(copied from my Gist at https://gist.github.com/dcht00/432caaf3e6c50a2202b8)

This did it for me on Trusty 14.04:

```
# Edit the sources file and add this to end:
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu precise main
sudo joe /etc/apt/sources.list

# You can't just install gephi because it's missing libgoogle-collections-java
# And that one's not packaged with Ubuntu anymore as of Trusty at least

# Download all three files to a temp folder:
# https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/libgoogle-collections-java

# Attempt to extract a source package
dpkg-source -x *.dsc

# DOES NOT WORK, NEED KEYS FIRST
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 974B3E96

# OK, again...
dpkg-source -x *.dsc

# Now try to build package.
cd libgoogle-collections-java-1.0/
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc

# Fail, needs dependencies
apt-get install maven-repo-helper maven-ant-helper cdbs
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc

# This builds an actual .deb in folder above.
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i libgoogle-collections-java_1.0-2_all.deb

# Now install gephi.
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install gephi

# Done
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in 14.04 Trusty and none of the suggestions worked for me. I ended up getting it working this way:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and add the following two lines:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu precise main
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main universe
```

then do:

```
sudo apt-get install libgoogle-collections-java gephi
```